# App crashes on zooming in/out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am getting a crash when I do zoom-in/zoom out gestures in the application and there are no definite steps to reproduce this. On a random basis app crashes when I do these gestures.

Any clue what could be missing?

Comment: What message is displayed over gdb? Also please specify zoom operation carried over a image /on a map/ anything else?

Comment: "Any clue what could be missing?" -- Yes. Enough detail in your question so we have a hope of answering! Please post the gdb stack trace and any relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when an app crashes randomly is cause of a broken algorithm or if it crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` it can be a memory problem